# Add attachment to auto respond Contact Form 7

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

Is it possible to add a PDF to the automatic responder of CF7 that people will receive?

I have tried using the attachment fields in mail 2, but it doesn't seem to attach anything. From the research I have made it seems this function is bugged? It says wrong path even though the path is correct.

**I tried using the following code without luck**

```html
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'send_attachment_file' );
 function send_attachment_file($cf7)
 {
 //check if this is the right form
 
if ($cf7->id==872)        // This is the form ID
 {
 $uploads = wp_upload_dir();     // will output the array of path,url,subdir,basedir,baseurl,error -- what we need is the path = '/home/euroling/public_html/beta/wp-content/uploads/2013/01'
 //define some constants
 define ('PRICE_UPLOAD_PATH',$uploads['path'].'/price');     // create price folder in the path
 // ...
 // ...
 if ($cf7->mail['use_html']==true)
 $nl="<br/>";
 else
 $nl="\n";
 //I omitted all the stuff used to create
 //the pdf file, you have just to know that
 //$pdf_filename contains the filename to attach
 //Let'go to the file attachment!
 
// $pdf_filename with the extenstion not just the filename
 $pdf_filename = "testnew.pdf";
 $cf7->uploaded_files = array( 'file_upload' => PRICE_UPLOAD_PATH .'/'.$pdf_filename );
 
//append some text to the outgoing email
 $message=$nl.$nl.'Blah blah blah.....'.$nl;
 $message.='So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish!'.$nl;
 $cf7->mail_2['body'].=$message;
 }
}
```

**Also is it possible to decide, which file is attached depending on which field is filled out? We have a dropdown with 5 options and we need a different PDF attached depending on the option chosen.**

Answer (score 1):

My bad. It seems that the attachment feature does work. See more at : https://contactform7.com/configuration-errors/file-not-found/

Make sure to use a relative path, such as: uploads/2018/03/Skarpeknive-gavekort.jpg